# How to get Sluggable and Timestampable behaviors in Symfony2 / Doctrine2 entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There appear to be several Symfony2 bundles that provide Sluggable and Timestampable behaviours for Doctrine2 and its not clear to me which is the best one to use. Furthermore, Im not using git and most of the install docs Ive read talk about adding these bundles as git submodules.

So Im asking which bundle should I install and is there a way to install just by updating the deps file and running "vendors install" instead?

Im hoping I can simply install the bundle, activate it and then add some annotations to my entities to use them.

Answer (score 8):

You can read through

http://gediminasm.org/article/timestampable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2

This library provides Sluggable , Translation and stuffs

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions

The stof bundle wraps the DoctrineExtensions for Symfony2

https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

You can read the help on Sluggable from

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#document

Hope this helps you.